# Как изменить цвет текста по умолчанию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Подскажите, как изменить цвет текста по умолчанию в программе написанной в kivy через .py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.label = Label(text=“hello”)
self.label.color = (1,1,1,1)

Comment: Большое спасибо!